# Is expecting an outcome based on past occurrences alone superstition?

Tags: belief

I have observed 2 phenomena so far, out of which the first i believed is superstition :

Phenomena 1 :
   Around 80% of the times some one said 'what a beautiful boy' my son has fallen sick. There is no basis for me to believe that it is anything other than co incidence. Though very unlikely, some one in future might find a cause and effect link.

Phenomena 2:
   According to theories of quantum mechanics, a phenomena called quantum entanglement predicted by works of physicist Neil's Bohr predicts that behavior of a particle in one point in space can affect another particle that is far away (even in a different galaxy) with no physical connection between them. This is yet to be proven true by experiment though a great deal of effort is being made. 
Technologies we use in everyday life and quantum computing is based on this theory. There is an excellent documentary in Amazon prime on this topic.

A troubling thing about it is that the theory has been disputed by Albert Einstein. So far the predictions of Einstein on space and time has been proven true after decades of numerous experiments and i believe he will be proven right this time as well.

If my belief regarding phenomena 2 based on my views in phenomena 1 superstition?

Comment: I would not call [1] superstition. 80% is high, whatever the cause. You could also be expectant of the outcome occurring again, but be skeptical towards "what a beautiful boy" being the cause. You could regard as it as a placemarker false cause until a better cause is found.

Comment: Quantum entanglement has been already demonstrated by [Aspect's experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect%27s_experiment), but the naive interpretation with "action at a distance" is erroneous, see the [no-signaling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem). It is an artifact of classical preconceptions about "particles", same preconceptions upon which Einstein's objections were based. Big name by itself isn't enough,  and beliefs based on comprehensive and corroborated theories are not comparable to those based on anecdotally observed correlations.